# No internet on Ubuntu Server 14.04 or 12.04

Tags: networking, server

I am relatively new at Ubuntu, and am trying to install Ubuntu Server on a commercial network at an academic institution.  When installing Ubuntu Desktop, I can automatically pull an IP address and get internet connectivity during installation.  However, if I install either Ubuntu Server 12.04 or 14.04 on the same hardware, I get a local IP address but do not have internet connectivity (cannot use apt-get or ping google).  We've tried using a static IP address, but to no avail.  I was allowed to test the hardware at my personal residence, and was able to get internet connectivity there.

Anyone know the reason we don't have internet connectivity with Ubuntu server but would with the Ubuntu Desktop?

Answer (score 3):

In a server, if you want a static IP address, which I recommend so that you can ssh and ftp into it, it is your responsibility to set the network details including DNS nameservers. I recommend you amend */etc/network/interfaces* to something like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback  

auto eth0  
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.125  
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
```

Substitute your details here. Be sure to select an address outside the DHCP pool in the router, switch, etc. Get the system to re-read and use the changes:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
```

Check:

```
ping -c3 192.168.1.1
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've worked with out IT admin to try multiple permutations of the static IP setup (to include dns-nameservers) but to no avail.  I've tried with both 12.04 and 14.04.  I'm in the process of reloading 12.04 and will attempt again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're doing during the installation that you don't get DHCP leased IP (I don't remember the installation process on Ubuntu Server right now out of my head) and not sure what you mean by "I get a local IP address, but do not have internet connectivity" - if you get proper IP from DHCP it should be fine, I'd say (have you checked routing btw?  - just in case?)

Anyway you may try to run dhclient command manually to get IP from DHCP server - or at least try to do that (with root privileges). And then see if you get connected properly to the network.
I guess dhclient should be installed by default, but if not - I'm pretty sure that your CD has the proper package to install.

Comment: by "local IP address" I mean that I can SSH in from the internal network, but cannot ping google

Comment: What about the default gateway - is it set properly?

Comment: If the default gateway is set in /etc/networkf/interfaces, then yes.  If somewhere else, maybe not.