# Ubuntu 14.04 Server - Networking Disabled upon Reboot

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, server, network-manager

I am a brand new user to ubuntu, so bear with me through this. I recently installed ubuntu 14.04 server on an old laptop to use as a media server. Installation went fine, upon rebooting though both wlan0 and p5p1 (from what I've read just a different name for eth0) are both network disabled.

I am physically connected to the AP using a known working cat6 cable, and am able to connect to the internet by issuing

```
sudo dhclient -v p5p1
```

or by entering ubuntu recovery and enabling network without rebooting.

Question:
How can I instruct the server to boot with the network p5p1 enabled? Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Please check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/543627/no-internet-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-or-12-04/